# blogger error could not save earnings settings

Tags: seo, blogger, adsense, google-ad-manager

When I try to save AdSense ad-display settings it gives the folloing error.

> Could not save earnings settings

[image]

What could be the problem? I already have infolinks ad on my blog. Should I remove that or both can be work together?

Please help.

Comment: If you downvote the question you should also comment why are you downvoting.

Comment: there are ppl who downvote without a word, but there is no rule written saying you have to comment if you downvote. However I would suggest you to talk to google directly. Their support is very good and fast.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be addressed by Google support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after lots of research I got the solution. Now I'm able to save earning settings.

The problem was that the attached adsense account to your blogger got expired. You need to reactivate your adsense account again.

[Reference](https://suraj1693.blogspot.com/2017/09/blogger-could-not-save-earnings-settings.html)

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced the same issue.

In my case, the only administrative user account of my Blogger was not linked to the AdSense account which had formerly been linked to. Maybe, I had removed the AdSense account's owner from the Blogger account.

First, I added the AdSense account's owner to the Blogger account again and tried to change it to an administrative user. But couldn't change.

Next, I added the administrative account of the Blogger to the AdSense account as a standard user. This was the solution. Once that was done, I could save earnings setting enabled on the Blogger.

Answer (score -2):

Was it working sometime earlier? If yes, then maybe clearing out the browser cookies and logging out of the website might help. Logging back in, should solve the problem. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RaiCNtyKgHI), is a possible solution.

Downvotes might be because it's more of a browser issue than a programming task.

Comment: thanks for your answer but not working as i have tried on different browsers and different computers also.

Comment: Then maybe try emailing the blogger team. It's an issue on their end most probably

Comment: i don't think so.

Answer (score -2):

Just go to bottom of the page, and click on "Switch AdSense account".Proceed with selecting the existing account option and your issue will get resolved.